# How to create a summary field on Opportunity to sum records on custom child object

Tags: roll-up-summary

Invoice line items are pushed against opportunities and I am trying to sum the total.

I have tried a rollup summary field, which will not work due to relationship

Has anyone done anything similar and provide help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you cannot change the relationship from Lookup to Master-Detail? The product allows this change ("Edit" the field then click "Change Field Type") for simple data models. If it doesn't get in the way of your business need it makes the rollup trivial. Doing the rollup with triggers is a lot harder.